# Manage display refresh rate/ resolution of a ROM via ssh?

Tags: screen, ssh, screen-resolution

Probably a silly question.. but
I have root ssh access to an android TV stick running openelec (on an sd card).

Long story short i am trying to figure out where the refresh rate/resolution settings could be stored, because an incorrect (higher) value that I had set seems to be preventing me to boot into the normal ROM.

I found this file, but something tells me its not the one to edit..

```
OpenELEC:/sys/class/video # cat frame_rate
VFrame rate is 0.00fps, and the panel refresh rate is 60, duration is: 35452,vsync_isr/s=59.99,vsync_pts_inc=1500
```

Any help Please ?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, but don't have android command like dumpsys in openelec. I am trying to find possible files that are responsible for refresh rate settings...I'll edit them manually

Comment: from the android interface! After that it won't boot into it.. so I can't change it from there...

Comment: Sorry, this is again a shot in the dark but when we change the resolution in the device using `adb shell wm size`, a key named [`display_size_forced`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java#L6272) is created in the table global of settings storage database. That key stores the new resolution. Deleting that key followed by a reboot restores the resolution to stock one. Does your Android TV have `wm`  or `settings` or `content` command?